# Obtener el tipo de Ram me devuelve siempre 0

Tags: c#

Estimadxs, estoy teniendo dificultades para obtener el Tipo de Ram instalada en la PC, para realizar la búsqueda del tipo hago lo siguiente:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnObtener_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblRam.Text = MotherboardInfo.Ram + " " + MotherboardInfo.TipoRam;
    }

    static public class MotherboardInfo
    {
        private static ManagementObjectSearcher ramSystemSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
        private static ManagementObjectSearcher ramTypeSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");

        static public string Ram
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach(ManagementObject queryObj in ramSystemSearcher.Get())
                    {
                        string _RAM = $"{Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(queryObj["TotalPhysicalMemory"]) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024))} GB";
                        return _RAM;
                    }
                    return "";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "¡Atención!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }

        static public string TipoRam
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    int tipo = 0;
                    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in ramTypeSearcher.Get())
                    {
                        tipo = Convert.ToInt32(queryObj["MemoryType"]);
                    }
                    return TypeString(tipo);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "¡Atención!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }

        //sirve para devolver el tipo de ram en String 
        private static string TypeString(int type)
        {
            string outValue = string.Empty;

            switch (type)
            {
                case 0x0: outValue = "Unknown"; break;
                case 0x1: outValue = "Other"; break;
                case 0x2: outValue = "DRAM"; break;
                case 0x3: outValue = "Synchronous DRAM"; break;
                case 0x4: outValue = "Cache DRAM"; break;
                case 0x5: outValue = "EDO"; break;
                case 0x6: outValue = "EDRAM"; break;
                case 0x7: outValue = "VRAM"; break;
                case 0x8: outValue = "SRAM"; break;
                case 0x9: outValue = "RAM"; break;
                case 0xa: outValue = "ROM"; break;
                case 0xb: outValue = "Flash"; break;
                case 0xc: outValue = "EEPROM"; break;
                case 0xd: outValue = "FEPROM"; break;
                case 0xe: outValue = "EPROM"; break;
                case 0xf: outValue = "CDRAM"; break;
                case 0x10: outValue = "3DRAM"; break;
                case 0x11: outValue = "SDRAM"; break;
                case 0x12: outValue = "SGRAM"; break;
                case 0x13: outValue = "RDRAM"; break;
                case 0x14: outValue = "DDR"; break;
                case 0x15: outValue = "DDR2"; break;
                case 0x16: outValue = "DDR2 FB-DIMM"; break;
                case 0x17: outValue = "Undefined 23"; break;
                case 0x18: outValue = "DDR3"; break;
                case 0x19: outValue = "FBD2"; break;
                case 0x1a: outValue = "DDR4"; break;
                default: outValue = "Undefined"; break;
            }

            return outValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Pero, el valor de `tipo` siempre es **0**, ¿Alguien sabe que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de consultar MemoryType, lee el campo SMBIOSMemoryType:

```
tipo = Convert.ToInt32(queryObj["SMBIOSMemoryType"]);
```

De esa forma a mi me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Suerte!

Comment: Excelentísimo aporte, muchas gracias